# I'm blocking an IP with dos.xml but still get requests from it

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I'm under a primitive DoS attack from a single IP. I added the IP to dos.xml and uploaded. In the console I do see that this IP was rejected 6,000+ times, but in the logs, I'm still seeing requests from that IP, although significantly less from before.

Isn't the IP blacklist supposed to block 100% of the requests?

Comment: You may want to try the newly released [GAE firewall](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/application-security#app_engine_firewall)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The primary purpose of the IP blacklisting service on app engine is to protect your application from running out of quota when subjected to denial of service attacks or similar forms of abuse.

Quoting form the [official doc](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/dos):

> Do not use this service for security. It is designed for quantitative abuse prevention, such as preventing DoS attacks, only. **Some requests from blacklisted users may still get through to your application.**

So what you see is normal according to the docs, some requests may still get through. The primariy purpose is to prevent your app reaching quotas due to some DOS attacks.

IP filtering and similar security features should be implemented in some other ways, e.g. using servlet filters or properly configuring your app in the [web.xml](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/webxml).